# How do I filter the command gcloud container operations list? What's the syntax?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

If you have 20 GKE clusters, gcloud container operations list returns too much data.

Google Cloud's official docs lack good examples of how to do filtering:

- Their docs just mention `--filter=[EXPRESSION]`, which isn't helpful at all without syntax of what the expressions should look like...
- `gcloud container operations list --help` just mentions see `gcloud topic filters` for more info, which tries to explain, but it's difficult to understand without examples.

**So the question is what should filtering look like?**

Answer (score 1):

```bash
export PROJECT=name-of-your-project
export CLUSTER=name-of-your-cluster

gcloud container operations list \
--filter="(targetLink ~ $CLUSTER) AND (2024-01-04)" \
--sort-by=START_TIME --format=yaml --project=$PROJECT

gcloud container operations list \
--filter="(targetLink ~ $CLUSTER) AND (startTime > 2024-01-04) AND (startTime < 2024-01-08)" \
--sort-by=START_TIME --format=yaml --project=$PROJECT

gcloud container operations list \
--filter="(targetLink ~ $CLUSTER) AND (startTime > 2024-01-08T06:18:55.104-08:00) AND (startTime < 2024-01-08T15:18:55.104-08:00)" \
--sort-by=START_TIME --format=yaml --project=$PROJECT
```

**Explanation of Syntax:**

- `--format=yaml` ends up improving verbosity (hidden feature), and tells you the accurate name of keys you can filter by.
  (that's how I identified targetLink and startTime as a valid keys)
- `--sort-by=START_TIME` is just handy
- `--filter` needs the "double quotes"
- "(true boolean expression) AND (true) AND (true)"
- `--filter="targetLink ~ $CLUSTER"`
  The ~ acts as a string in value of key
  so string "$CLUSTER" is contained within the long string value of key named targetLink
  If you have 20 clusters this lets you filter the results to a single cluster :)
- `--filter="2024-01-04"`
  This checks for that string in the value of all keys
  Let's you check the operations that occurred on a particular day.
- `--filter="(startTime < 2024-01-06)"`
  Is also valid and handy if you want to see entries before a particular date. Note the key always has to be on the left, startTime can't be on the right side of the inequality.